# How to handle SIGWINCH in haskell?

Tags: haskell, signals, posix

Hi I'm new to Haskell and been working on some Haskell code to handle signals on POSIX system.

Especially I want to handle `SIGWINCH` with Haskell

I googled about them and saw some documents on Hackage but I'm not pretty sure I can do something with it.

Then I found some post about mixing with C code like this below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void sig_handler(int sig) {
    if (SIGWINCH == sig) {
        printf("you resized terminal\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGWINCH, sig_handler);
    while (1) {
        pause();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but I'm curious about something more in 'Haskell way', without any C codes.

I found an example about handling `SIGINT` signal but couldn't find anything about `SIGWINCH`.

How can I handle it in Haskell?

Comment: Check out [`System.Posix.Signals`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.4.0.0/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html). Note that `SIGWINCH` isn't strictly POSIX and hence defined separately in [`System.Posix.Signals.Exts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.4.0.0/docs/System-Posix-Signals-Exts.html) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should allow you to install a handler to handle the (non-standard) `SIGWINCH` POSIX signal:

```
import System.Posix.Signals
import System.Posix.Signals.Exts

main :: IO ()
main = do
  installHandler sigWINCH (Catch handler) Nothing
```

where `handler` is an action of type `IO ()`.

Happy Haskelling!